# I want to build my own "explode" function, but I have some problem

Tags: python, explode

I want to build my own explode function without using built in function.

I did

```
def exp_ (a)

  out_ = []

  if out is None:
     out_ = []
  out.append(str[:1])

  if len_(str) > 1:
    explode(a[1:])
  return
```

---

put `exp_("hello")`

than, my output is `['h']`

I want `['h','e','l','l','o']`

without using append. (I already build len function, so dont worru about it)

Comment: There is about 5 typos errors before your code compile, between wrong function naming and wrong parameter naming

Comment: this code is full of syntax errors.  you're mixing out and out_, and str[:1] should be a[:1].  your recursive function call should be exp_ instead of explode.  It's impossible that this code gives you output ['h']

Answer (score 0):

You need to `extend` with the next method call.

```
def exp_(a):
    if a is None:
        return []
    out_ = [a[:1]]
    if len(a) > 1:
        out_.extend(exp_(a[1:]))
    return out_
```

Note, if this is not for learning purposes only, you really shouldn't do that; don't reinvent existing code, because your `explode` is just `list(a)`.